# Did John Milton ever mention Martin Luther directly or indirectly?

Tags: john-milton, martin-luther

Martin Luther’s auspicious life on earth began in 1483 A.D. and he got salvation in the year 1546 A.D. John Milton’s scared life began in 1608 and he went to God’s abode in the year 1674 A.D.

As far as I know, Mr. Luther’s ideas were very much accepted and celebrated, as of evangelists themselves, in his own lifetime. Mr. Milton wrote his “On his being arrived at the age of twenty three” when he was 23 years old so the year would have been 1631, and that poem showed clearly the love of Milton for God. Mr. Luther’s “The 95 Theses” were found hanging in the year 1517. Now, what I conjecture is if Mr. Luther was accepted so much in his own life time then he would have been much more accepted after more than 100 years and even that in England. Mr. Milton loved God, Mr. Luther made teachings of Christ clearer, so what I think is that how Mr. Luther’s ideas could’ve affected those of Mr. Milton? Did Mr. Milton made any allusion to him directly or indirectly? All I can find is that Milton used the word *Protestant* in a para (quoted by Thomas Hardy) which goes like this

> Whoso prefers either Matrimony or other Ordinance before the Good of Man and the plain Exigence of Charity, let him profess Papist, or Protestant, what he will, he is no better than a Pharisee. — J. Milton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milton commented on Luther's influence on him (from [English Opinion of Luther](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1507549.pdf), quoting Milton's *An apology for Smectymnuus*):

> John Milton confesses that he "had not examined through" Luther's works, and was certainly not deeply indebted to him.

However, Milton mentions Luther by name several times in his works.

According to [Reason, Republic, Regicide](https://ir.ua.edu/bitstream/handle/123456789/3022/file_1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), in Milton's *The Tenure of Kings and Magistrates*:

> the most significant addition to the second addition was the inclusion of extensive “testimonies” of Protestant divines, appended to the end of the work.
> Ranging from Luther to Thomas Cartwright, the citations represent a broad swath of orthodox theology seemingly at odds with the radical proposals of the first edition.

In *Judgement of Martin Bucer Concerning Divorce*, Milton quotes Jacobus Verheiden of Grave's opinions on Bucer and Luther. Other works in which Milton briefly mentions the name *Luther* include *Animadversions upon the Remonstrants Defence*, and *in answer to Salmasius's Defence of the king*.

All these examples can be found in [The Prose Works of John Milton](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/griswold-the-prose-works-of-john-milton-2-vols).